# Cannot find usb on installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have a big problem during the installation of ubuntu onto a USB drive. I use UNeetbootin or whats it called to create the bootable usb. I got the ISO file from your site. Everything works good until i get to the installation. When i am on the installation type window and choose "Something else" option my usb drive which i booted from doesn't show up in the list of avalible devices. The usb is a ms-DOS FAT drive so it is bootable. My OSX drives shows up and so on but not my actuall USB drive which i want to install it on. Ive read tutorials on the forum and how to install ubuntu but cannot fiure out how i am going to fix this issue.

My operating system is: OSX el Captain the latest version. Updated yesterday.
My USB drive is: 8 GB

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install OS to the installation drive itself. You should get another USB drive and use one for the installer, the other as the install destination.